# A Simple Integrate

Tags: plotting, equation-solving, calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration, boundary-conditions

I'm facing the integral

```
   Clear["Global`*"]
   FullSimplify[Integrate[1/Sqrt[-k + f/3 x^2 + b*(x^(2 - 3 m)) ], x],Assumptions -> {k > 0, x > 0, f > 0, b > 0, m > 1}]
```

I used Mathematica to solve it but not any solution is coming up?

The restrictions on the parameters are:

`k=1, f>0,m>1, b>0`

Comment: As long as I know m is 4/3

Comment: Then why don't you set m to 4/3? ``Integrate[1/Sqrt[-k + f/3 x^2 + b*(x^(2 - 3 *4/3))], x]`` evaluates normally to ``(Sqrt[-3 b + 3 k x^2 - f x^4] ArcTan[(3 k - 2 f x^2)/(2 Sqrt[f] Sqrt[-3 b + 3 k x^2 - f x^4])])/(2 Sqrt[f] x Sqrt[-k + b/ x^2 + (f x^2)/3])``.

Comment: typo in last comment. Are you sure there is a solution for m other than 1 or zero? many integrals can **not** be solved analytically.  V 13.2 can solve it for m=1 and m=0 with no other assumptions on the other parameters.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica SE. To start: 1) take the [introductory tour](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), since the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) consider accepting the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking checkmark sign](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Answer (score 5):

Taking into consideration the comment:

`As long as I know m is 4/3`

which was made by the author of the OP

```
FullSimplify[
 With[{m = 4/3}, 
  Integrate[1/Sqrt[-k + f/3 x^2 + b*(x^(2 - 3 m))], x]], 
 Assumptions -> {k > 0, x > 0, f > 0, b > 0}]
```

> [image: int1]